# Laravel5 MySQL + MongoDB relations

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel-5

I'm using both mysql and mongodb models on my laravel5 app (with the https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb library).

I am able to query for a mongodb model and then fetch the related mysql model but it doesn't work the opposite way (mysql-grab-related-mongodb-records), it just retrieves an empty array.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/SbjSiUZU

Comment: Great question! I would also really like to know what the solution is. Did you already found it by yourself?

Comment: Not yet, just added static function to retrieve relations....